# TFS 2012 MTM: There are no test cases matching the criteria specified. Use Microsoft Test Manager to view the test cases

Tags: tfs, microsoft-test-manager

Today we run BDT test case and face following error from TFS MTM:

> There are no test cases matching the criteria specified. Use Microsoft
>   Test Manager to view the test cases

We have only moved same test case to another test plan and it runs pass.

From [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9873a985-03ee-4964-9f72-042a665510bd/there-are-no-test-cases-matching-the-criteria-specified-use-microsoft-test-manager-to-view-the-test?forum=vslab) say it may be caused by permission issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Later we found out the root cause was that we have not included test configuration in test plan.
But the test configuration is already configured and used by BDT build definition.

So solution is just to include the test configuration into test plan.

Answer (score 0):

Did you update your build definition to point to the new Test Plan and Suite?  The error sounds like you have your BDT build pointing to a Test Plan/Suite that no longer exists.